# Plot the convex hull in FDA plot - R

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

I am trying to add a convex hull for each group in this plot using ggpubr package? Why it does not work?

Code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(ggpubr)
library(data.table)

irisfda <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = mars)
  
df1 <- cbind(data.frame(irisfda$fit$fitted.values), species = iris[,"Species"])

ggplot(df1) +
  geom_point(aes(X1, X2, color = species, shape = species), size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = "FDA1",y = "FDA1") +  
  stat_chull(aes(color =  species, fill =  species), geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't told `stat_chull` where the x and y points are. You told `geom_point` where they were, but geoms and stats don't inherit from each other when you add them to a plot. You can either just add the x and y co-ordinates to `stat_chull` or, better yet, add them to the `ggplot` call. *Then* `stat_chull` can inherit them, *and* you can save on some typing.

Incidentally, you used `library` calls for dplyr, MASS, scales and data.table, which aren't needed for this example, but you forgot to put the library call for `mda`, which *is* needed:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(mda)

irisfda <- fda(Species ~ ., data = iris, method = mars)
df1 <- cbind(data.frame(irisfda$fit$fitted.values), species = iris[,"Species"])

ggplot(df1, aes(x = X1, y = X2, color = species, shape = species)) +
  geom_point(size = 2.5) + 
  labs(x = "FDA1",y = "FDA1") +  
  stat_chull(geom = "polygon", alpha = 0.1)
```

[image]